# Why skipping unsigned char breaks the program?

Tags: c++, c, avr, avr-gcc

I want to send messages via UART interface, I had the following program:

```cpp
#ifndef F_CPU
#error "F_CPU has to be defined"
#endif

#ifndef CONSOLE_BAUD
#pragma message "CONSOLE_BAUD was not defined, using 9600"
#define CONSOLE_BAUD 9600
#endif
#define UBRR_VALUE F_CPU/16/CONSOLE_BAUD-1

// init
UBRRH = (unsigned char)(UBRR_VALUE >> 8);
UBRRL = (unsigned char)UBRR_VALUE;
UCSRB = (1 << TXEN);
UCSRC = (1 << URSEL) | (1 << USBS) | (3 << UCSZ0);

// send
while (!(UCSRA & (1 << UDRE)));
UDR = 'A';
```

This doesn't work. The HEX being sent is `00`.

I changed that to the following:

```cpp
#ifndef F_CPU
#error "F_CPU has to be defined"
#endif

#ifndef CONSOLE_BAUD
#pragma message "CONSOLE_BAUD was not defined, using 9600"
#define CONSOLE_BAUD 9600
#endif
#define UBRR_VALUE F_CPU/16/CONSOLE_BAUD-1

// init
unsigned int ubrr = UBRR_VALUE; // changed
UBRRH = (unsigned char)(ubrr >> 8); // changed
UBRRL = (unsigned char)ubrr; // changed
UCSRB = (1 << TXEN);
UCSRC = (1 << URSEL) | (1 << USBS) | (3 << UCSZ0);

// send
while (!(UCSRA & (1 << UDRE)));
UDR = 'A';
```

And it started to work. Why is that? What's the difference between assigning the preprocessor directive directly to UBRRX and having an intermediary variable?

// EDIT
The question was marked as a duplicate although I had no chance to find the linked duplicate, since I did not see the issue (lack of parentheses) in the first place. I think that marking my question as a duplicate is unfair.

Comment: This is why I always put parentheses around my value defines.

Comment: @Gerhardh You can see `#define UBRR_VALUE F_CPU/16/CONSOLE_BAUD-1` in both code snippets above

Comment: @MichaelMyers How does the original code work for you with 1 change: `#define (UBRR_VALUE F_CPU/16/CONSOLE_BAUD-1)`?  `()` added.

Comment: mnj,  Posting the definitions of `UBRR_VALUE F_CPU`, `CONSOLE_BAUD` would be useful.

Comment: With 16-bit `int/unsigned`, `UBRR_VALUE >> 8` may be a _signed_ shift vs. `ubrr >> 8`, an _unsigned_ shift.  If `UBRR_VALUE < 0`, then different results.

Comment: Note that bit shifting is commonly specifically done on unsigned rather than signed values. Of concern is right shift of a negative value, as it is implementation defined whether an arithmetic or logical shift is done in that case.

Comment: @Barmar, closure reason is premature.  Yet only [crickets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpGtBnVZLSk) from OP.

Comment: How is my question a duplicate? If I knew that adding parentheses changes anything, I'd probably go in that direction. I did not know that.

Comment: Alright, after reading the question that mine is supposedly a duplicate of, I don't see any connection between them other than the fact that we're both using `#define`. Could someone explain what's the issue here?

Comment: FYI, in C++, the `operator<<` is overloaded for stream insertion.  You may want to remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I guess it's overloaded for Streams only, when my operands are numbers, the "normal" bit shift operation is executed.

Comment: Try to add `#define CONSOLE_BAUD 9600UL` -> `UL` and `#define UBRR_VALUE (F_CPU/(16UL * CONSOLE_BAUD) - 1UL)`. Shifting seems to be ok!